# Any secure backdoor for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, security, remote-control

I want to install a backdoor to my laptop with Windows 8 so that I can access it and stay hidden, just in case if someone will steal it. Most of remote access tools are not hidden and it is obvious if they are being used. Most of "hacker's" backdoors seems to be insecure and don't even require a password. Are there any remote control tools which are

1. Secure
2. Hidden
3. Free
4. Preferably open source

?

Comment: Someone's been watching too many movies...

Comment: Seems like a great technique as well to be used for EVIL!! ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that in some jurisdictions it's illegal to hack your own laptop if someone else is using it (privacy laws).

Comment: Not in my country :)

Comment: For evil things there are enough insecure backdoors

Comment: There is no need for a (il)legal descussion, since the question will be closed as off topic resource request.

Comment: Arqwer - there are many remote management tools available. Recommending tools is not usually considered on topic here, as so much depends on your specific environment. Why not select one of the ones a Google search brings up?

Answer (score 3):

Creating additional security flaws in your device so you can access it in the event it is stolen is the wrong way of going about this. Instead of planning for this scenario, instead put effort into preventing this scenario from occurring (ie: keeping the device safe and not randomly leaving it unattended in public).

If you need to keep the contents secure in the event the device is unfortunately stolen then you should look at encrypting the contents of the device.

From the [ten immutable laws of security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722487.aspx), see law 3:

> If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore.

If the computer has been stolen from you, it's no longer yours, it's no longer secure and you can no longer guarantee the integrity of anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a backdoor to enhance security is not a good idea because you're basically adding another attack vector. Besides, you're screwed if someone else is in physical posession of your computer. Even if you get your computer back, how can you tell that it didn't came back backdoored? A better idea would be to always keep an eye on your laptop, and encrypt your hard drive to prevent others from extracting your personal data in case someone manages to steal your laptop.

Comment: +1 "encrypt your hard drive" - First priority should be to prevent others accessing your data. If they can't log-in to you pc they'll reinstall it, which obviously means they also delete the backdoor.

Answer (score -1):

No software is helpful if your computer is physically stolen. If you want to keep your machine safe, keep an eye on it.

Comment: Of course I understand that. But having access to it is much better than not having access :)

Comment: @Arqwer If the thief really cares, he/she can simply format your hard drive... I don't think any one steal computers for his/her personal use! lol

Comment: @Arqwer It sounds like the purpose you described in your question is not your actual purpose, man!

Comment: Well, the only thing I didn't mention, that computer is often stolen by people living with me.

Comment: @Arqwer BINGO :-)

Comment: How do you want to "access" it? Also, please see comment from @mtak under your question.

Comment: If it was Linux, i'd simply use ssh, but in windows it seems that ssh server requires a window to be opened so it is not hidden.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/501802)

Comment: @Chenmunka Does any other answer really answer the question? :-)